# Unable to update changes of Gridview to database

Tags: c#, winforms

Unable to update changes to database after editing the gridview. There are no errors thrown, but changes are not updated in table in database. I am using Sql server here and I have two Winforms called Form1 and Form 2. A button(btnSearchAll in Form1) opens the gridview in Form2 with all the data loaded. When I try to edit the data in gridview(in Form2) and tried to update, it is not updating the changes. Please help

Below is my Form 1:

```
    namespace Tailor_app
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=(local);Database=MSNETDB;Integrated Security=true;");
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataTable dt;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=(local);Database=MSNETDB;Integrated Security=true;");
        txtFirstName.Focus();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Measurement", con);
        da.Fill(ds, "Measurement");
        dt = ds.Tables["Measurement"];
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        cb.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.CompareAllSearchableValues;
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["CellNumber"] = txtCellNo.Text.Trim();
            dr["FirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
            dr["LastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
            dr["Shirt"] = txtShirt.Text;
            dr["Pant"] = txtPant.Text;
            dr["DueDate"] = txtDueDate.Text;
            dr["Date"] = txtDate.Text;
            if (dr["CellNumber"] == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Cell Number");
            }
            else if (dr["CellNumber"] != "")
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                MessageBox.Show("Success");
            }

                try
                {
                    da.Update(ds, "Measurement");
                }
                catch (DBConcurrencyException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    dt.Clear();
                    da.Fill(ds, "Measurement");
                }
        }

    private void btnSearchAllCustomers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        frmDgv_SearchResult frm2 = new frmDgv_SearchResult();
        frm2.Show();

        using (da = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            try
            {
                da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * From Measurement", con);
                ds.Clear();
                da.Fill(ds,"Measurement");
                dt = ds.Tables["Measurement"];
                frm2.dgvSearchResults.DataSource = dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Below is my Form 2:

```
namespace Tailor_app
{

public partial class frmDgv_SearchResult : Form
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=(local);Database=MSNETDB;Integrated Security=true;");
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dt;

    public frmDgv_SearchResult()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void dgvSearchResults_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

      private void frmDgv_SearchResult_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Measurement", con);
        da.Fill(ds, "Measurement");
        dt = ds.Tables["Measurement"];
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        cb.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.CompareAllSearchableValues;
    }

    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
            {
                da.Update(ds, "Measurement");
            }
            catch (DBConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                dt.Clear();
                da.Fill(ds, "Measurement");
            }
            finally
            {
                MessageBox.Show("success");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try requesting the Update commands for your Data Adapter :-

```
  private void frmDgv_SearchResult_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Measurement", con);
        da.Fill(ds, "Measurement");
        dt = ds.Tables["Measurement"];
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

        cb.GetInsertCommand();
        cb.GetUpdateCommand();
        cb.GetDeleteCommand();

        cb.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.CompareAllSearchableValues;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `dt.AcceptChanges();` after insert, update or delete. `AcceptChanges` commits all the changes made to your data table since the last time `AcceptChanges` was called

Comment: dt.AcceptChanges(); has no affect, I don't know why it is not working. sqlcommandbuilder handles all insert, update and delete. So I guess I don't to declare sqlparameters.add. All I have to do is dataAdapter.update("TableName"); and it should work but don't know why its not working. Any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

mine looks more like this:

```
da.Fill(dt)

Dim cb As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)

da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey     ' includes default field value settings
da.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand      ' instantiate for transaction
da.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand
```

Comment: Tried every thing, still not working. Please Help I have been asking every one from two three days and still haven't got any solution. Looking on Goolge for similar question but couldn't find any.

Comment: are the insert and update command properties of the data adapter set?  also, you need a unique key on the server side so it can identify the row to update.

Comment: I am using command builder for insert and update. I have the ID as auto increment in database but I haven't given any code or functionality for the ID column.

Comment: if you print the value of da.insertcommand, what does it return?